# Revit API - Create new ScheduleField

Tags: c#, revit-api, revit, pyrevit

I'm trying to create a new field in my sheet list schedule programmatically with C# in the revit-api but I'm running into issues. I've found how to add a regular OOTB field [here](http://help.autodesk.com/view/RVT/2016/ENU/?guid=GUID-F66DF1E1-7EF2-4CD5-AA3F-9DEA7D92DC49) but it doesn't mention how to create a new field and then add that.

For example how to add a "Sheet Order" field and a "Sheet subOrder" field.

Any and all help/direction is appreciated. I've been crawling the web and the [Revit API docs](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2019/31528702-22e7-f515-5edc-9356585e3bc1.htm) but haven't found anything yet about adding new fields.

Answer (score 0):

ended up reading a couple of articles explaining that [it wasn't possible](https://spiderinnet.typepad.com/blog/2011/05/parameter-of-revit-api-31-create-project-parameter.html) and that shared parameters are superior so I ended up [going that route](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=362&v=i8Evm753qgM&feature=emb_logo).